# Bokeh click button to save widget values to txt file using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I want to do something like this. I create a few widgets, for example a dropdown list , a multiselect box and a text input box. Then I add a button. When users select the variables in the widgets and click the button. The values they have selected will be downloaded as txt files. I want this html to be usable without bokeh server so I would appreciate if someone can get it done through customJS.

Really appreciate it.

```
from random import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

savebutton = Button(label="Save", button_type="success")
savebutton.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(multi_select1.value,multi_select2.value), code="""
        var value1 = multi_select1.value;
        var value2 = multi_select1.value;

        var out = "";
        for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
            out += value1[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < value2.length; i++) {
            out += value2[i];
        }
        var file = new Blob([out], {type: 'text/plain'});
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        elem.download = 'selected-data.txt';
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
        """)

assets=['asset1','asset2','asset3','asset4']
multi_select1 = MultiSelect(title="Select:", value=['asset1'],options=assets, height=200, width=100)
multi_select2 = MultiSelect(title="Select:", value=['asset1'],options=assets, height=200, width=100)

plot = column(multi_select1,multi_select2,savebutton)
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, looks like i figured it out by myself. Hope it helps for other people.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

x = ['asset1']
source= ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x))

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var input = cb_obj.value;
    data['x']=input;
    source.change.emit();
""")

assets=['asset1','asset2','asset3','asset4']
multi_select1 = MultiSelect(title="Select:", value=['asset1'],options=assets, height=200, width=100)
multi_select1.js_on_change('value', callback)


savebutton = Button(label="Save", button_type="success")
savebutton.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.data;
        value1=data['x'];
        var out = "";
        for (i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
            out += value1[i];
        }
        var file = new Blob([out], {type: 'text/plain'});
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        elem.download = 'selected-data.txt';
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
        """)


plot = column(multi_select1,savebutton)
show(plot)
```